# Use '~' for user home directory in jsconfig.json in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, tilde, vscode-jsconfig, tsconfig.json

In the includes in my `jsconfig.json` file, I want to use the tilde character ~ to expand to the current user's home directory, since I work on the same project on multiple computers with different usernames. It seems like the ~ doesn't work, however. Is there an accepted way to do this?

I've tried:

```
{
  "include": [
    "*.js",
    "**/*.js",
    "~/.vscode/extensions/samplavigne.p5-vscode-1.2.14/p5types/global.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Expected to work the same as

```
{
  "include": [
    "*.js",
    "**/*.js",
    "/Users/mngyuan/.vscode/extensions/samplavigne.p5-vscode-1.2.14/p5types/global.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

but no typeahead suggestions appear anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I see this as an XY problem. You can just `npm install -D "@types/p5~1.2.14"`.

And no, I am not aware of a way to refer to abstractly refer to a user's home directory in the `include` property of a jsconfig.